# How to make another connection with different port in Docker?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, docker

I make a program that running PHP Job with 2 different Port Database in Docker. Here is the docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
        image: 'shouts.dev/laravel'
        container_name: shouts-laravel-app
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
        networks:
            - laravel-shouts
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mariadb:latest'
        container_name: shouts-laravel-db
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - ./database/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - laravel-shouts
    clickhouse:
        networks:
            - laravel-shouts
        container_name: clickhouse
        image: clickhouse/clickhouse-server
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:8123:8123
            - 127.0.0.1:9000:9000
            - 127.0.0.1:9009:9009
networks:
    laravel-shouts:
        driver: bridge
```

---

I have 2 Databases in Docker. ClickHouse RED-BOX (port 8123) and MySQL GREEN-BOX (port 3306) :

[DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKWd5.png)

I success to make connect with MySQL the GREEN-BOX (port 3306) as you can see below :

[GREEN CONNECTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy1q6.png)

here the source codes for MySQL GREEN-BOX (port 3306) from .env :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sakila
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

And here the source codes for MySQL GREEN-BOX (port 3306) from database.php :

```
'sakila' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => 'mysql',
            'port' => '3306',
            'database' => 'sakila',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

And after that, i try to take data from MySQL GREEN-BOX (port 3306) and success. Here the result :
[GREEN RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ry9u.png)

---

Next i try to make another connection with ClickHouse RED-BOX (port 8123) but it failed, wont connect or connected.

here the source codes for ClickHouse RED-BOX (port 8123) from .env :

```
DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=clickhouse
DB_HOST_SECOND=clickhouse
DB_PORT_SECOND=8123
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=jaya
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=default
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=
```

here the source codes for ClickHouse RED-BOX (port 8123) from database.php :

```
'clickhouse' => [
            'driver'   => 'clickhouse',
            'host'     => 'clickhouse',
            'port'     => '8123',
            'database' => 'jaya',
            'username' => 'default',
            'password' => '',
            'options'  => [
                'timeout'  => 1000,
                'protocol' => 'http'
            ]
        ],
```

And after that, i try to take data from ClickHouse RED-BOX (port 8123) and Error. Try to change the Source Codes but the error are Connection Refused or Unsupported Driver. Here the result :

[RED-BOX ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltl15.png)

---

I think my Source Codes are wrong, but i dont know exactly how's the right method. What is the right one, please ? I am confused

Comment: What errors do you receive? Which [driver client library](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/third-party/client-libraries/) are you using?

Comment: @Phil Sorry, Sir. I update the error above. May u check, please.

Comment: Looks like you haven't included a driver. Laravel doesn't have one out-of-the-box

Comment: @Phil Do you have any solution, Sir? like how to add another connection or else?

Comment: There's a [Laravel driver](https://packagist.org/packages/glushkovds/phpclickhouse-laravel) listed in the link I posted above. Searching for "laravel clickhouse driver" also yields several results

Comment: You might find these error messages easier to read if you reconfigure your application to produce plain-text output rather than PNG messages.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the image links with the actual text of the errors?  How are you starting the application and the databases; is there something like a `docker-compose.yml` file that's a key part of this setup?

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry, Sir. i update the docker-compose.yml above || For the error you can ignore it i think. Because i dont really have idea about that, i just try it out to connect database with different port.